# Single page application using django-Nav Bar for django app

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, single-page-application, django-apps

In Angular,we can use routing to create SPAs . So I can have a navigation bar that's common for all templates(or written only once). Basically only required part of the page loads everytime .
But in django,so far I haven't seen anything like it. **Do i have to include the code for the Nav bar in each template file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write single time in any html file you can name whatever you want for example `_base.html` is the file which contains navbar code then i want to insert in every other html file then i just have to enter tag `{% extends '_base.html' %}` at the top of the other files and that will load the _base.html there as well. If you need more relevant code you can consult that repository as well https://github.com/wsvincent/djangox